# Is it possible to push to an array the same time as I add an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'd like to push a value to an array the same time I add an object to it. Is this possible?
Here is a short demo of my code:

```
let abc = [
  [],
  {}
];

$('form').find('input').each(function() {
  // This works but I'd like to do it in one step if possible
  abc[0].push(this);
  abc[1][this.name] = 'Text';

  // I'd like to change it to something like this
  abc = [
    this,
    this.name: 'Text'
  ];
)};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you need the ES6 spread operator

```
abc = [
  [ ...abc[0], this ],
  { ...abc[1], [this.name]: 'Text' },
  ...abc.slice(2)
];
```

More information can be found here

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831

Comment: `name: 'Text' }` would need to be `[this.name]: 'Text' }`